# plus/minus (\pm) sign appears misaligned with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

Consider the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$1\pm2$
\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex (texlive 2018) without unicode-math yields

[image]

whereas compiling with unicode-math (uncommenting the corresponding line) yields

[image]

Clearly, the \pm sign is too low in the second case.  I observe the same phenomenon with xelatex, and with e.g. \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}.

Any hint to fix the issue would be welcome.

Comment: First question with a MWE: Great! :) I added a possible duplicate.